# Is it possible to record desktop screen with html5?

Tags: html

Html5 can be used to record camera [HTML5 solution to upload a webcam/camera video stream to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431251/html5-solution-to-upload-a-webcam-camera-video-stream-to-server)

What if instead of camera, I want to record user desktop screen ?

Comment: what about this ? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this library: https://mgechev.github.io/jscapture/

Maybe you can implement this on your website.